# Git branch nesting itself

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have a local git branch when I push this branch to remote. I see my local branch nesting itself  on the remote branch:

Local branch structure:

```
source_code
|
|- images
|- fonts
|- index.html
```

Remote branch structure:

```
source_code
|
|- images
|- fonts
|- index.html 
|- source_code
   |- images
   |- fonts
   |- index.html
```

When I try to pull it, I don't see this folder on my local branch.

I'm not sure, what is causing this issue. Can anyone please help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you paste the error message output from git? It'd be very useful for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directory structure

```
source_code
|
|- images
|- fonts
|- index.html 
|- source_code (*)
   |- images
   |- fonts
   |- index.html
```

Because someone mistake when Copy (or Ctrl + drag-n-drop) or something mistake another. Solution: Delete folder `source_code` (*), then

```
git add .
git commit -m"Remove unnecessary folder"
git push -v
```

everything will ok.